# Having problems with binary search c++

Tags: c++, binary-search

Im having a problem with a binary search function. It only seems to work when the randomly generated search key is already in the middle position of the array. Ive tried a lot of things but cant seem to figure out why it's doing this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

void printarray(int[], int);

void fillarray(int[], int);

void descendingSort(int[], int);

int binarySearch(int[], int, int);

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));


    bool quit = false;

    while (quit == false)
    {



        int key = rand() % 100 + 1;

        const int size = 16;
        int mainarray[size] = {};


        fillarray(mainarray, size);

        printarray(mainarray, size);

        descendingSort(mainarray, size);

        cout << endl;

        cout << "Ordered array after selection sort:" << endl;
        printarray(mainarray, size);

        cout << endl;

        int result = binarySearch(mainarray, size, key);

        cout << "Searching for key value " << key << endl;

        if (result >= 0)
        {
            cout << "Key value " << key << " found at position " << result << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Key value " << key << " not found!" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Continue (y/n)? :";
        char x;
        cin >> x;
        cout << endl;

        if (x == 'y')
            quit = false;
        if (x == 'n')
            quit = true;


    }



    return 0;
}


void printarray(int array[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
}

void fillarray(int random[], int size)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++)
    {
        random[j] = rand() % 100 + 1;

    }
}

void descendingSort(int array[], int size) 
{
    int max, next;

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        max = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (array[max] < array[j])
                max = j;
        }

        if (max!= i)
        {
            next = array[i];
            array[i] = array[max];
            array[max] = next;
        }
    }
}

int binarySearch(int array[], int size, int key)
{
    int low = 0, high = size - 1;
    int mid;

    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (key == array[mid])
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (key < array[mid])
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: ...to 'work' when the randomly... -- eh?  what is it that does not work?

Comment: By not working I mean that the program is supposed to return the position in the array that the key used in the binarySearch function is in. Its supposed to return either not found or "key value x found at position y" but it only returns not found or  position 7 (which is the middle of the array) if the key happens to be there. sorry if this is confusing im not sure how to word it completely.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are sorting in descending order, your case is backwards. 
See code below where I replaces `>` with `<`

```
if (key == array[mid])
{
    return mid;
}
else if (key > array[mid])
{
    high = mid - 1;
}
else
{
    low = mid + 1;
}
```

By adding some code above the `if` it allowed me to visualize what was going wrong.

```
cout << "Searching in: ";
for (int i = low; i < high + 1; i++)
{
    cout << array[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I knew it had to be something simple-ish but i couldn't find it for the life of me.